# UITouch / UIEvent - delaying the event?

Tags: uitouch, uievent

Is there any way to delay the event of this touchBegan function?

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *followTouch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

bull.center = [followTouch locationInView:followTouch.view];}
```

Comment: Why would you want a delay? Are you looking for dispatch_after()?

Comment: I have a UIImageView that is chasing the position of another UIImageView which is touched and dragged on the screen.

Comment: I don't understand what having a UIImageView has to do with anything.

Comment: the UIImageView is the object with a center property = UITouch location

Comment: I was just wondering if the UIEvent touchesBegan can be delayed?

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is a UIPanGestureRecognizer to trigger an animation. Probably the easiest way is to use one of the UIView animation methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. It animates the movement of a square a half second after the touch moves:

```
-(void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [pan locationInView:self.view];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.square.center = touchLocation;
    });
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIView *square = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
    square.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.square = square;
    [self.view addSubview:square];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}
```